# Average marginal effects for censored regression (Tobit) in R

Tags: r, marginal-effect, tobit-regression

I would like to calculate average marginal effects for a Tobit regression in R.

`margEff.censReg` can calculate marginal effects at the mean, but not average marginal effects (the mean over marginal effects over all observations)

The `margins` package can calculate average marginal effects e.g. for a linear model, but does not seem to work with the packages that are able to estimate a Tobit model. I tried:

- `censReg` (`Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('censReg', 'maxLik', 'maxim', 'list')`) and
- `vglm` (`Error in get(dat, envir = env) : first argument has length > 1`)

Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: Have you tried the `marginaleffects` package?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to compute average marginal effects
using censReg (without s.e.)

`library(AER)`

`library(censReg)`

`library(tidyverse)`

`data("Affairs")`

`c.tobit <- censReg(affairs ~ age + yearsmarried + religiousness + occupation + rating, data = Affairs)`

`af <- cbind(1,Affairs[,names(coef(c.tobit))[2:6]])`

`as_tibble(t(apply(af,1,FUN = function(x) margEff(c.tobit,x) ))) |> summarise(across(everything(), mean))`

You should get

age yearsmarried religiousness occupation rating

-0.0459        0.142        -0.431     0.0834 -0.585

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `censReg` just won't work with `margins` and lots of post-regression operations. Using `AER::tobit` to run your tobit model will be more compatible and faster as well.